# Starting to NUnit in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a new guy to unit testing in .NET and I want to start with NUnit. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 for creating my project. Where can I start to learning NUnit? Can you suggest me some tutorials please?

NOTE: I'm **NOT** new in ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC and C#

NOTE: I have some experiences with unit testing in RoR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can learn NUnit using Osherove's tutorial and book. Or something called unit testing kata.

Read [Art Of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) by Roy. Good read.

Link to kata testing: [Unit Testing Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/)